# iCarousel is been shown up in previous page when clicked the back button

Tags: ios, iphone, icarousel

When i press the back button. the `iCarousel` is still shows up for 1 second.why is this happening and how to stop this.I have used storyboard to create a iCarosel view..

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.carousel = nil;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    carousel.delegate = nil;
    carousel.dataSource = nil;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
  return [idOfAllWords count];
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = nil;

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250.0f, 250.0f)];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];
        label.tag = 1;
        [view addSubview:label];
    }
    else
    {
        label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];
    }
    Words *word=nil;
    word=idOfAllWords[index];
    label.text =word.Name;
    return view;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you been able to fix it?

Comment: @GenieWanted Hiding and unhiding is not the solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually tried to reproduce your problem and did see that the carousel view stays for a second when 'pop' or back button press happens. This particularly happens when you the carousel is swiped and then the back button pressed. As a workaround, I was able to fix it by setting the iCarousel hidden in the `viewWillDisappear` method.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{

[YOUR_CAROUSEL_NAME setHidden:YES]; //This sets the carousel to be hidden when you press Back button

}
```

If this looks to be hidden suddenly, you can perhaps try setting the alpha to 0.0 inside an animation block. Something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{

//[YOUR_CAROUSEL_NAME setHidden:YES]; 
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
   [YOUR_CAROUSEL_NAME setAlpha:0.0f]; //This makes the carousel hide smoothly
}];

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @raman Hiding and unhiding is not the solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Hiding and unhiding is not the solution. What you need is just one line:

```
yourCarousel.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: @instaable- i already tried yourCarousel.clipsToBounds = YES; but not working

Comment: @vivek you have to set this in the controller's viewDidLoad.